# Rebuilding single package with catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a catkin workspace with a lot of packages. Now, if I make changes to CMakeLists.txt in one of the packages, how do I rebuild only that single package, provided my changes do not concern any other package (e.g. other packages need not to be rebuilt)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113931/rebuilding-single-package-with-catkin/) by [AStudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/10326/astudent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-12-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
catkin_make --pkg [YOUR_PACKAGE]
```

should do what you are asking for.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it rebuild only the package but it does not rebuild actually because any change has not been done. How can I rebuild one package from the beginning as like it is a new one? catkin clean PKG command does not work.

---

Originally posted by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) with karma: 86 on 2019-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-25**:
If you're just looking to get changes to `CMakeLists.txt` picked up, you could add `--force-cmake` to your `catkin_make` invocation.

**Comment by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) on 2019-09-25**:
Thanks, it works as you told!

```
catkin_make --pkg <YOUR_PACKAGE> --force-cmake
```